# Using OpenCV and manual point clicking to do stereo calibration

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

This is the code that I have so far. I fist did single camera calibration on both images, got the intrinsic parameters and used them to perform stereo calibration using opencv.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Define the number of corners in the calibration pattern
num_corners_x = 4
num_corners_y = 3

# Create arrays to store object points and image points from all calibration images
object_points = []  # 3D points in real-world space
image_points_left = []  # 2D points in the left camera image plane
image_points_right = []  # 2D points in the right camera image plane

# Prepare the grid of object points
objp = np.zeros((num_corners_x * num_corners_y, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:num_corners_x, 0:num_corners_y].T.reshape(-1, 2)

# Specify the folders containing calibration images for the left and right cameras
left_images_folder = r'path to images'
right_images_folder = r'path to images'


# Get the list of image files in the left and right folders
left_image_files = sorted(os.listdir(left_images_folder))
right_image_files = sorted(os.listdir(right_images_folder))
# Create a display window
cv2.namedWindow('Calibration Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

# Mouse callback function for manual corner selection
def select_corners(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        corners = param[0]
        image = param[1]
        corners.append((x, y))

        # Draw a circle to mark the selected corner point
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)
        cv2.imshow('Calibration Image', image)

# Iterate through each calibration image for the left camera
for image_file in left_image_files:
    # Load the image
    image_path = os.path.join(left_images_folder, image_file)
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Create a copy of the image for corner selection
    img_corners = img.copy()

    # Display the image for corner selection
    cv2.imshow('Calibration Image', img_corners)

    # Create an empty corner list
    corners = []

    # Set mouse callback function for manual corner selection
    cv2.setMouseCallback('Calibration Image', select_corners, param=[corners, img_corners])

    # Wait for corner selection to be completed
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # If enough corners are selected, add them to the list for the left camera
    if len(corners) == num_corners_x * num_corners_y:
        image_points_left.append(np.array(corners, dtype=np.float32))
        object_points.append(objp)

# Clear the window for right camera corner selection
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Iterate through each calibration image for the right camera
for image_file in right_image_files:
    # Load the image
    image_path = os.path.join(right_images_folder, image_file)
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Create a copy of the image for corner selection
    img_corners = img.copy()

    # Display the image for corner selection
    cv2.imshow('Calibration Image', img_corners)

    # Create an empty corner list
    corners = []

    # Set mouse callback function for manual corner selection
    cv2.setMouseCallback('Calibration Image', select_corners, param=[corners, img_corners])

    # Wait for corner selection to be completed
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # If enough corners are selected, add them to the list for the right camera
    if len(corners) == num_corners_x * num_corners_y:
        image_points_right.append(np.array(corners, dtype=np.float32))

# Perform camera calibration for the left camera
ret_left, camera_matrix_left, dist_coeffs_left, rvecs_left, tvecs_left = cv2.calibrateCamera(
    object_points,
    image_points_left,
    img.shape[::-1][1:],
    None,
    None
)

# Perform camera calibration for the right camera
ret_right, camera_matrix_right, dist_coeffs_right, rvecs_right, tvecs_right = cv2.calibrateCamera(
    object_points,
    image_points_right,
    img.shape[::-1][1:],
    None,
    None
)

# Check if the calibration was successful for both cameras
if ret_left and ret_right:
    print("Camera calibration successful.")
else:
    print("Camera calibration failed.")

# Perform stereo calibration
flags = (cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)


criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
ret, camera_matrix_left, dist_coeffs_left, camera_matrix_right, dist_coeffs_right, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
    object_points,
    image_points_left,
    image_points_right,
    camera_matrix_left,
    dist_coeffs_left,
    camera_matrix_right,
    dist_coeffs_right,
    img.shape[::-1][1:],
    criteria=criteria,
    flags=flags
)

# Save the calibration results to a NumPy .npz file
np.savez("stereo_calibration_results.npz",
         camera_matrix_left=camera_matrix_left,
         dist_coeffs_left=dist_coeffs_left,
         camera_matrix_right=camera_matrix_right,
         dist_coeffs_right=dist_coeffs_right,
         R=R,
         T=T,
         E=E,
         F=F)

# Create a folder to save the undistorted images
undistorted_images_folder = r"C:\Users\wstkw\Research\07_11_2023\SUCCESSFUL_CALIBRATION\CALIBRATION_2"
os.makedirs(undistorted_images_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Undistort and save the calibrated images
for i in range(len(left_image_files)):
    # Load the left and right images
    left_image_path = os.path.join(left_images_folder, left_image_files[i])
    right_image_path = os.path.join(right_images_folder, right_image_files[i])
    img_left = cv2.imread(left_image_path)
    img_right = cv2.imread(right_image_path)

    # Undistort the images
    img_undistorted_left = cv2.undistort(img_left, camera_matrix_left, dist_coeffs_left)
    img_undistorted_right = cv2.undistort(img_right, camera_matrix_right, dist_coeffs_right)

    # Save the undistorted images
    undistorted_left_image_path = os.path.join(undistorted_images_folder, "undistorted_mono_" + left_image_files[i])
    undistorted_right_image_path = os.path.join(undistorted_images_folder, "undistorted_ir_" + right_image_files[i])
    cv2.imwrite(undistorted_left_image_path, img_undistorted_left)
    cv2.imwrite(undistorted_right_image_path, img_undistorted_right)

# Close the display window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The undistorted images are very wrong. What is wrong with my code?
I am using IR images (240*250) and monochromatic images (2592*2048)